# How to use a razor variable mixed with html ID text?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting an error because the razor and html is getting confused by the compiler I imagine.

```
<div id="@Model.MyLabelCars" ...>
```

My model variable is:

```
Model.MyLabel
```

The "Cars" is just raw text that should be in the HTML.

So say Model.MyLabel's value is "123" the ID should be:

```
id="123Car"
```

How can I seperate the model's variable name and HTML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use regular string add operator

```
<div id="@(Model.MyLabel + "Car")"></div>
```

Or C# 6's string interpolation.

```
<div id="@($"{Model.MyLabel}Car")"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use the `<text></text>` pseudo tags

`<div id="@Model.MyLabel<text>Cars</text>" ...>`